# Dropzone Messy UI when handling multiple file uploads

Tags: javascript, dropzone

I'm practicing File Uploads using Dropzone. Whenever I upload multiple files, Dropzone creates additional boxes that tend to clutter up the web page. Is it possible to make these boxes disappear when they finish uploading?

Messy UI when handling multiple Files:

[image]

Single File upload looks ok:

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Its good to have some screenshots of your UI as well as some of your existing codes so that we could understand your question more.

Comment: Welcome to the community! You need to be a little more specific, provide screenshots and elaborate on your question.

Comment: Hey guys! Thank you so much for taking the time. I've edited the post to add screenshots.